# Hudson FileSet includes

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

Can anyone explain how the FileSet includes work in hudson? Maybe with a simple example.
What if i want the archiver to list all the *.jar in my workspace for the various builds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the help says:

> Can use wildcards like
>   'module/dist/**/*.zip'. See the
>   [@includes of Ant fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) for the
>   exact format. The base directory is
>   the workspace.

Example:  `*.jar`